# cgo doesn't export functions in imported packages

Tags: go, cgo

I'm trying to build existed Go package into C shared library and header using [CGO](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/).

I built the package with `-buildmode c-shared` as documented.

```
-buildmode=c-shared
    Build the listed main package, plus all packages it imports,
    into a C shared library. The only callable symbols will
    be those functions exported using a cgo //export comment.
    Requires exactly one main package to be listed
```

And used `//export Func` to expose functions as C symbols.

All `//export` functions in `main` package are exported properly. However when I moved those functions to sub-package (with `//export`), those functions are not exported. I imported the sub-package in `main` package, too.

Here's my code.

*main.go*

```
package main

import "C"

import (
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/onosolutions/archanan-cgo/c"
    "math/rand"
)

// FuncInMain generates a random integer.
//export FuncInMain
func FuncInMain(max C.int) C.int {
    return C.int(rand.Intn(int(max)))
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("Hello World %d!\n", int(FuncInMain(256)))
}
```

*c/c.go*

```
package c

import "C"

import (
    "math/rand"
)

// FuncInSubPackage generates a random integer.
//export FuncInSubPackage
func FuncInSubPackage(max C.int) C.int {
    return C.int(rand.Intn(int(max)))
}
```

Then only `FuncInMain` is exported.

I read through [CGO documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/), but there's nothing saying about exporting in sub-packages. The only clue I got is through `go help buildmode`, but it said that all imported sub-packages will be compiled. I'm not sure whether it isn't supported or I missed some configurations.

I'd love to achieve that to be able to modularize `//export` functions.

Comment: I don't have much experience using CGO, but I'd try importing those packages as dot-imports

Comment: @PhucTran Why would `FuncInSubPackage` ever show up as a symbol in the main package? Importing as `_` means it's unused except for initialization side-effects, so there's no way to access the symbols. Go packages are always independent, make a simple pure go proof of concept to see what's going on.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I tried dot imports, it doesn't work either.

Comment: Got your idea @JimB, I didn't notice the meaning of import as `_`.

Answer (score 0):

Both of them have own `C.type`, so as far as I know, there's no way to import function with `C.type` but using linking.

I didn't tried, but give it a chance:

```golang
import _ "unsafe"

//go:linkname FuncInSubPackage c.FuncInSubPackage
//export FuncInSubPackage
func FuncInSubPackage(max C.int) C.int
```

Comment: It doesn't work. But I understood what you mean, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: the main point is that functions can be exported only from "main" package and imported golang's C types are different, so if above one does not work then it's impossible, wrapping or copy paste is required.