# c++ access extern in cgo

Tags: c++, go, cgo

I am using this:

```
// foo.h
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
  void foo();
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

//foo.cc
void foo() {
  cout << "Hello World" << endl;
}
```

to link between my cgo process and c++ process. I want to access a golang function from my c++ function `foo`. My go looks like:

```
// #include "foo.h"
import "C"

func golangPart() {
  //do stuff in go
}

func main() {
  C.foo()
}
```

I want to access `golangPart()` from the c++. I have tried this:

```
//foo.h

void golangPart();

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
  void foo();
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

//foo.cc

void foo() {
  golangPart();
}
```

But it gave me this error:

> ./foo.cc:42: undefined reference to `golangPart()'
>
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: You must mark any Go function that you want callable from C (or C++) code, using the `export` comment. This only works for package `main`; see https://stackoverflow.com/q/58433624/1256452.

Comment: I would also place the declaration of `golangPart` under the `extern "C"` scope as it should obviously use C linkage as well.